# How can I allow concurrent reads but block all access during a write on an object in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

If I have a data structure in a multithreaded application that I want to access simultaneously with reads while it's not altered, but disallow both read and write access to other threads while one is writing?

For simplicity, let's say I have an array and two methods `read()` and `write()`:

```
int[] rgData;

// ...

int read(int ix) {
    return rgData[ix];
}

void write(int ix, int val) {
    rgData[ix] = val;
}
```

In reality, the data structure and the two access methods are more complex. Now, if I use Java's object monitors and wrap the calls to `read()` and `write()` like this

```
synchronized (rgData) {
    int val = read(ix);
}
```

I don't have simultaneous reads anymore, which is sad, because simultaneous reading is no problem and writes are rare.

One solution could be to do all read and write jobs through a common manager that maintains a queue and a thread pool. Read jobs are run concurrently, if a write jobs comes in, it waits for all running jobs to complete, and the queue is not processed while the write job runs. But is there anything simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [ReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).  It does exactly what you need.

Comment: This was an answer race condition. Accepted yours and upvoted dtsazza's

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the [ReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html), introduced in Java 1.5 which handles exactly this situation.

Comment: This was an answer race condition. Upvoted yours and accepted chilitom's